# Does setting a precise position of the base matter when using RTK and you only care about relative position?

Tags: rtklib

I'm using RTKLIB with my own rover and base station. Most of the time I have a "float" solution. Would setting a more accurate position of the base station in the RTKLIB settings help to have more a "fix" solution? I don't care about an absolute solution, only relative.

Comment: Base is normally there to have much longer measurements and thus a better precision isn't it? I don't know why you only got a 'float' solution. Do you have an explanation?

Comment: @s.k What do you mean with much longer measurements? The base is sends data real time to the rover.

Comment: @s.k I think you can take an avarage for a long time, but I just wanted to know if the precise position setting matters. :)

Comment: And where do these data comes from? I mean, are they processed, if yes by whom? Are they externally processed or directly within the base/laptop? Giving more informations on the configuration set could be better to help us understanding your situation. And if you don't need a precise positioning, I mean, the answer is in the question...

Comment: @s.k [the base](http://imgur.com/C6S27de) is connected to the laptop that just sends data over wifi to Raspberry Pi that also has a receiver and where RTKLIB is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the precise position of the base doesn't matter if you only care about the relative position.  A lack of accuracy in the base position is not what is keeping you from getting a relative fix.

Answer (score 0):

No, It doesn't matter if base position is precise or just averaged.

As solution, it is sometime useful to try less GNSS i.e. GPS alone